# RecyclerView and SQLite Custom OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

Hello everyone I am trying to create fitness app where user can create their custom workout. I am trying to create that via Recycler View and SQLite database. So far I was able to create successful system of adding workout to database and delete the same one.
What I was unable to do is OnClickListener for item of Recycler View. 
I was able to create OnClickListener for position,but what I really want is to save previously edited activity as onlclicklistener for particular item of recyler view.

This is what I've created so far and I want to create :

[image: This is state of my RecyclerView before I add workout]

[image: When I click FloatingActionButton I go to this activity where I enter information about my workout]

[image: After I press "create custom workout" button based on radiobutton number I go to activity,which in this case has one plus icon only]

[image: When I press my pluss ImageView I have popup alert dialog where I can choose which color of plus I want to (Basically changing ImageView)]

[image: I am wondering how to set previously changed ImageView in new activity which will be called by onclicklistener of "first" item]

What I really need here is to save red plus icon instead of blue (picture 3 & 4) and load it
when I click on "first". I also want to make it reusable so I can add workout again.

This is code for my Adapter :

```
    private Context mContext;
private Cursor cursor;
private ListItemClickListener listItemClickListener;

public WorkoutsAdapter (Context mContext,Cursor cursor,ListItemClickListener listItemClickListener)
{
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.cursor = cursor;
    this.listItemClickListener = listItemClickListener;
}




@NonNull
@Override
public WorkoutsAdapter.WorkoutsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item,parent,false);

    return new WorkoutsViewHolder(view);
}




@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WorkoutsAdapter.WorkoutsViewHolder holder, int position) {





    if(!cursor.moveToPosition(position))
    {
        return;
    }


     long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(WorkoutsContract.WorkoutsEntry._ID));
    holder.itemView.setTag(id);

    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WorkoutsContract.WorkoutsEntry.WORKOUT_NAME));
 holder.workout_name.setText(name);



}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();
}




public class WorkoutsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView workout_name;
    public WorkoutsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        workout_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.word);
         itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }





    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        listItemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}




public void swapCursor (Cursor newCursor) {
    if (cursor != null)
    {
       cursor.close();
    }

    cursor = newCursor;

    if (newCursor != null)

    {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

This is my second fragment where view is stored and where I want to apply clicklistener to create saved activity :

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_2_layout, container, false);

    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });


   DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
   mydatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = getAllTasks();
    adapter = new WorkoutsAdapter(getActivity(),cursor,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




      new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
          @Override
          public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
              return false;
          }

          @Override
          public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

              long id = (long) viewHolder.itemView.getTag();
              removeTask(id);
              adapter.swapCursor(getAllTasks());
          }
      }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);



    return v;
}

private void removeTask(long id) {

    mydatabase.delete(WorkoutsContract.WorkoutsEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            WorkoutsContract.WorkoutsEntry._ID + "=" +id,null);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Wokrout Is Deleted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private Cursor getAllTasks ()
{
    return mydatabase.query(WorkoutsContract.WorkoutsEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            WorkoutsContract.WorkoutsEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    adapter.swapCursor(getAllTasks());
}



@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {

    long id = (long) view.getTag();



    System.out.println(position);
```

Comment: Are you facing any errors? Or the code works but the data is unable to be updated in the DB? In short, please elaborate on your problem. Also, if you are facing errors, please post logcat to help us better understand your issues.

Comment: Firstly I wanna thank you for fast response. Secondy I want to say that I'm really sorry because I forgot to precisely describe  my problem. I am new to android development.I have no clue on how to do this, to be more accurate I am wondering how to save activity, for example on photo (3/4),when I load activity I got one imageview which is blue plus button,I changed it to red and I want to save activity with red button and make it clicklistener for item in RecyclerView (photo 5). If you need further explanation regarding this problem it would be awesome to ask me.

Comment: I am glad if I can help you. I need to better understand your exact problem statement. Are you willing to have a detailed discussion?

Comment: Yes, of course, I would be glad to contact you, is there any way we can proceed to further conversation ?

Comment: Are you online?

Comment: Sorry I have been out of country for few days, are we able to share our social media on this forum so I can provide you further information about my project?

Comment: It is never advised to share your personal details on public forums. You can try searching my name, Atish Agrawal, over google and you will definitely reach me.